# PrimeNG Schedule throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when lazyloading

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

Currently I get an exception when lazy loading the events. I followed [PrimeNG doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule)

**Exception**

```
AppComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'.
at viewDebugError (VM29065 core.umd.js:9794) [angular]
```

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nBpBA6vSQcT06FePB8ID)**

PrimeNG 5.2.3, Angular 5.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually trigger *change detection* in your component by using [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) in order to solve your problem.

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}
```

and call `detectChanges` method after adding your events

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

**EDIT**

Why not loading events in `ngOnInit` method ?

*HTML*

```
<p-schedule [events]="events"></p-schedule>
```

*TS*

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.events = [
            {
                "title": "All Day Event",
                "start": "2018-04-19"
            },
            {
                "title": "Long Event",
                "start": "2018-04-07",
                "end": "2018-04-10"
            },
            {
                "title": "Repeating Event",
                "start": "2018-04-09T16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Repeating Event",
                "start": "2018-04-16T16:00:00"
            },
            {
                "title": "Conference",
                "start": "2018-04-11",
                "end": "2018-04-13"
            }
        ];
  }
```

See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TNpKgIwranqSe9P2xBfk?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But why should I call it manually? It is not part of the docs. Or is it because thet use a promise?

Comment: *Or is it because thet use a promise?* I think so.

Comment: This method is not working properly I see. Every event is shown 3 times. Any clue? See your Plunker

Comment: Thanks but this is the initial setup without lazyloading. When loading events via onViewRender I've the possibility to use the start and end variables of 'event.view' to load only the events for the particular start/end date. It seems that it is working properly when using a promise instead of an observable